# Python define column name in variable

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I'm writing a script for ArcMap

what I want is

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(featureClass) #open a cursor from data source
row = rows.next()
AddressFieldName = "row.ADD_FULL"
while row:
    s = AddressFieldName
```

but it doesn't work.
originally

```
s = row.Add_FULL #Add_FULL is field column name
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: what you expect and what actually doesn't work? any errors? what is your current output?

Comment: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax when I use s = row + . + AddressFieldName and tried other ways that I could think of but about same

Comment: Please provide full error log (edit your question with adding log). Also let me know what is `ADD_FULL` method (I can't find description in google) and why you define `s` in 3 different ways: as string- `"row.ADD_FULL"`, as method applying to `row` - `s = row.Add_FULL` (what is correct form `ADD_FULL` or `Add_FULL`???) and in some kind of mystery way- `s = row + . + AddressFieldName`?

Comment: I got this using s= row.getValue(AddressFieldName)

Comment: This is the 4th definition of `s` :) Can you make required corrections to your question using following tips: specify input, your current code, error log, expected output... For now your question make no sense

Comment: row.ADD_FULL: ADD_FULL is just a field name from table

Comment: if so, you can not use it in this way `s = row.Add_FULL` as this will raise an Exception

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you do want to extract the field names of a Feature class and maybe the field values as well. You could try the following codesnippet:

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(sourceFeatureClass)
fields = arcpy.ListFields(sourceFeatureClass)
fieldnames = ""
for field in fields:
    fieldnames += field.name
fulldata=""
for row in rows:
    data = ""
    for field in fields:
        data += row.getValue(field.name)
    fulldata += data
```

This way you do get all your fieldnames in "fields" and the data either per row in "data" or the all data of the featureclass in "fulldata"